# IntelliJ IDEA plugin development: How to run profile sequentially

Tags: intellij-plugin

I'm developing an IntelliJ plugin(for Pycharm). I'm trying to run multiple python scripts as a task queue, of which the scripts can be executed in parallel OR sequentially.

I already made it work to run in parallel with the following codes.

```java
class SomeClass{
    
    protected void runConfiguration {
        // ...
        PythonRunConfiguration configuration;
        // ...
        Executor executor = DefaultRunExecutor.getRunExecutorInstance();
        
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironmentBuilder.create(executor, configuration).build();

        // With this line, the "task" runs asynchronously(as the results show)
        ExecutionManager.getInstance(project).restartRunProfile(env);
    }
}
```

How to run the task(an `ExecutionEnvironment` object or any kind of  configuration) sequentially?